# How to set boolean Array from hashtables´s Object

Tags: java

I have this :

```
 public class NewClass {
String DNI;
String name;
boolean asist [][]=new boolean[3][4];

public NewClass(String DNI, String name) {
    this.DNI = DNI;
    this.name = name;
    for (int i=0;i<asist.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<asist[0].length;j++)
        {
            asist[i][j]=true;
        }
    }
}
public String getDNI() {
    return DNI;
}

public void setDNI(String DNI) {
    this.DNI = DNI;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean[][] getAsist() {
    return asist;
}

public void setAsist(boolean[][] asist) {
    this.asist = asist;
}
```

and I saved this code in HashTable < String,Object> has=new HashTable();.

Ok then I want to set asist[0][0] and i dont know how to do this  I tryed this:

```
    has.get(key).setAsistencia([0][0]false)
```

Thanks and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close.
First you need to retrieve the array and then set the respective part of it to false.

```
has.get(key).getAsist()[0][0] = false;
```